# Attach event to elements from ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add a show event to a set of div's coming in as ajax response, basic setup looks like this:

```
Call -> Ajax success -> append X amount of divs
```

the div's look like this:

```
<div>Content <a href="#" id="showaddcontent-1">Show additional Content</a></div>
<div class="hidden" id="hiddendiv-1">Additional content</div>

<div>Content <a href="#" id="showaddcontent-2">Show additional Content</a></div>
<div class="hidden" id="hiddendiv-2">Additional content</div>
```

And so on.

I tried adding the click function to each link and the show function to each div like this:

```
$(function() {
var foreachid = 0;
$.ajax({ 
....
success: function(html){
    $('[id^="showaddcontent-"]').each(function() {
    var foreachid = foreachid + 1;
    $(document).on('click', '#showaddcontent-'+foreachid, function(){
    $( "#hiddendiv-"+foreachid ).show();
   });
});
```

What seems to be the problem here ?

Comment: You only need 1 event handler - use `this` and get the `next` `hidde`n div and show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you need to attach the event listener:

```
$(function() {
     $(document).on('click', 'div[id^="showaddcontent-"]', function() {
         var foreachid = this.id.split('-').pop();
         $( "#hiddendiv-"+foreachid ).show();
    });

    $.ajax({ 
        //....
        success: function(html){
           //obtain data and append divs to DOM
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Had to change it to: `$(document).on('click', '[id^="showaddcontent-"]', function() {` but works fine now, thanks !

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of help.